# Posting a file with cURL, but not knowing the Key for the POST

Tags: php, file, post, curl

I'm attempting to use the [WoT Dossier](http://wot-dossier.appspot.com/service/dossier-to-json) service to convert a dossier to JSON, and in their [FAQ](http://wot-dossier.appspot.com/#!faq), they show the following cURL example:

```
curl --data-binary @dossier.dat http://wot-dossier.appspot.com/service/dossier-to-json
```

After hours of scratching my head as to what's going wrong, I've had no luck. Here's the code I use (PHP) to attempt to replicate the command:

```
$url = "http://wot-dossier.appspot.com/service/dossier-to-json";

$file = realpath('dossier_temp/' . $full_fn);

echo $file;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/octet-stream"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("@$file"));

$curl_res = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($curl_res, true);
```

A `var_dump()` of the json shows NULL, but how can this be? Is there an error in the postfield somewhere?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't include an array in the postfields, try this. it seems your post just needs to be a raw datastream.

```
$data = file_get_contents($file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Comment: If you're ever in the neighborhood, I'll buy you a beer. Cheers.